# QuestDB and Vertx + Micrometer

Tags: vert.x, micrometer, questdb

I am trying to use QuestDB as a replacement for InfluxDB but looks like it is not working.

```
MicrometerMetricsOptions options = new MicrometerMetricsOptions()
      .setInfluxDbOptions(new VertxInfluxDbOptions().setUri("http://localhost:9009").setDb("qdb").setEnabled(true))
      .setEnabled(true);
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setMetricsOptions(options));
```

I took the DB name as qdb from quest postgres example given. Removing it doesn't make any change.

Can someone assist in what should be the settings to use with vert.x / Quarkus / Micrometer.

Comment: QuestDB supports Influx Line Protocol, but unlike InfluxDB it accepts data over plain TCP or UDP socket. On the other hand, InfluxDB accepts ILP data over HTTP, so most likely you'll need a custom plugin to integrate vert.x / Quarkus / Micrometer with QuestDB.

Comment: @AndreyPechkurov This is the error I get in Vertx. I think the issue is the DB name

21:20:50.586 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR i.m.influx.InfluxMeterRegistry - unable to create database 'default'

Comment: I tried with qdb as well. Same issue

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, QuestDB now supports the ILP protocol over HTTP, so it can be a drop-in replacement for ingestion